# code to figure out lowercase vowels, python question

Tags: python

I have a question in my home work assignment,
The user enters a string of all lowercase letters. The python program is suppose to tell them whether or not the string contains a lowercase vowel somewhere

, the problem I have is when i enter lets say more then letter I they all comeback wrong. Like if I enter
(ab)
it will come back saying all of there are no lower case vowels.
If my text has at least one vowel, it should print "Contains a lowercase vowel!"

I added a picture to help show more

my OG code in case my picture does not load

x = input("Enter a string of lowercase letters: " )

c = ('a','e','i','o','u')

for c in x:

```
if x in (c):

     print ("Contains a lowercase vowel!")

else:
    print ("Doesn't contain a lowercase vowel.")
```

Comment: Use `any`: `any(c in 'aeiou' for c in your_string)` or a set: `set('aeiou') & set(your_string)`

Comment: Please post some code in order to illustrate what you tried so far. That will help the comunity help you. Otherwise you may use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strng = input('Enter Your String: ')
v = 0

for ch in strng:
    if ch in 'aeiou':
        v+=1

if v>0:
    print('Contains Lowercase Vowels...!')
else:
    print('No lowercase vowel..')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this in Python.

All of the methods rely on the fact that strings in Python are iterable (ie, you can loop over them).

Given this string:

```
>>> st='xyzabc'
```

You can check if any of those characters are in the string `'aeiou'` with [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> any(c in 'aeiou' for c in st)
True
```

(The portion inside the any function is a Python [comprehension](https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Comprehensions.html) - something you will need to understand in Python)

You can also use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) intersection:

```
>>> set('aeiou') & set(st)
{'a'}
```

Or a list comprehension that filters:

```
>>> [c for c in st if c in 'aeiou']
['a']
```

Comment: I will definitely read up on the comprehension link. The college class I am going threw they really don't talk about comprehension a whole lot. (or at least super in depth so I am still a little foggy on it)